# Is there any way to flush the docker DNS cache (internal)?

Tags: docker, docker-network

I'm using Docker `18.03.1-ce` and if I create a container, remove it and then re-create it, the internal DNS retains the old address (in addition to the new).

Is there any way to clear or flush the old entries? If I delete and re-create the network then that flushes it but I don't want to have to do that every time.

I create the network:

```
docker network create -d overlay --attachable --subnet 10.0.0.0/24 --gateway 10.0.0.1 --scope swarm -o parent=ens224 overlay1
```

Then create a container (SQL for this example)

```
docker container run -d --rm --network overlay1 --name sql -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=Some_SA_Passw0rd' -p 1433:1433 microsoft/mssql-server-linux
```

If I create an Alpine container on the same network I can `nslookup sql` by name and it resolves to `10.0.0.6`. No problems, so far-so-good.

Now, if I remove the SQL container and re-create it then `nslookup sql` shows `10.0.0.6` and `10.0.0.8`. The `10.0.0.6` is the old address and no longer alive but still resolves.

The nameserver my containers are using is `127.0.0.11` which is typical for a user-created network but I haven't been able to find anything that will let me clear its cache.

Maybe I'm missing something but I had assumed the DNS entries would be torn down whenever the containers get removed.

Any insight is certainly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I have just fixed the same problem by running containers in Docker Swarm. Seems like Swarm does something to keep DNS entries up to date. I tried to remove my application container manually using *docker rm*, scaled it up/down - in every case it's hostname was correctly resolved to existing IP addresses only.

If you can't use Swarm, I guess another solution would be to run a standalone service discovery tool (maybe in another container) and configure your other containers to use it as DNS server instead of a build-in one.

Comment: Thank you. When I run a stack it also keeps the DNS updated. It does appear to be a problem only when using individual containers which makes development a bit tedious but I can't complain too much for a free product.

Comment: I run service in swarm mode, but it does not resolve after loading a service. I removed the service, and stack deployed the service as new, and it does not work. I tryed `docker service update` and it does not work. All services are on the same overlay network shared by all nodes, the two service whose are supposed to communicate are in 2 different node.
I think I can complain anyway, it is supposed to work, and documented as such. I am going to fill a bug report about it mainstream